# Combinatorics Question about Generating Functions and Multisets

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, multisets

I am faced with the following question from my undergraduate Combinatorics class:

There are n aisles in a shop. We want to separate them into consecutive nonempty groups for different categories of items. Also, each category will be colored white, black, or grey, and we'll select a nonempty subset of the categories to be shown in a magazine. Let h<sub>n</sub> = the number of ways to do this. Express H(x) = $\sum_{n\ge0} h_nx^n$ as a rational function.

We are currently studying compositions of generating functions. I understand that the idea is to let $a_n$ be a sequence which is the number of ways to pick something of order, $b_n$ is the number of ways to pick the subsets,... and then compose H(x)=B(A(x)).

What I am struggling with is how exactly to define $a_n$ and $b_n$ in terms of the given information. For example, I thought about saying $a_n$ = # ways to assign white/black/grey to n aisles and $b_n$ = # ways to pick a non-empty subset of n items. But, I don't know how to account for the fact that the aisles will be given colorings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the number of ways to break $n$ aisles into groups of consecutive aisles.  One group may contain $1,2,3, \dots$ aisles, so its GF is 
$$z + z^2 + z^3 + \cdots = \frac{z}{1-z}$$
The shop consists of a sequence of such groups, so the GF for the number of ways they can be selected is
$$F(z) = \frac{1}{1 -\frac{z}{1-z}} = \frac{1-z}{1-2z}$$
(You may recognize $F(z)$ as the GF for the number of "compositions" of an integer.)

A set of $n$ objects can be three-colored in $3^n$ ways, so if the GF for some collection objects is $a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + a_3 z^3 + \dots$, then the GF for the number of ways to three-color the objects is $a_0 + 3 a_1 z + 3^2 a_2 z^2 + 3^3 a_3 z^3 + \dots$.

So the GF for the number of ways to three-color our collection of aisles is
$$G(z) = F(3z)$$

Finally, the number of ways to select a non-empty subset of $n$ objects is $2^n-1$.  If a collection of objects has GF $a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + a_3 z^3 + \dots$, then the GF for the number of ways to select a non-empty subset is $(2-1) z + (2^2-1)z^2 +  (2^3-1)z^3 + \dots$.

So the GF for the number of ways to select a non-empty subset of the three-colored aisle collection is
$$H(z) = G(2z) - G(z)$$